# C fwrite() structure to file

Tags: c, file, gcc, structure, fwrite

## Greetings,

Noob in C looking for some help concerning `fwrite()` a c structure to a .txt file.

After execution, I a get the .txt file containing some rubish symbols instead of my structure.
(Z�<�U���;�U3�y`T����;�U�v ���;�U�y)

Here is my simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct Motorcycle
{
 char company[20];
 char model_name[20];
 char engine_type[40];
 int engine_volume;
 int price;
 bool available;
};

int main()
{
struct Motorcycle Motorcycles[4]=
        {
         {"Harley Davidson","IRON 883","V-Twin: air-cooled",883,10765,true},
         {"Harley Davidson","STREED 750","V-Twin: water-cooled",750,7690,true},
         {"Harley Davidson","FORTY-EIGHT","V-Twin: air cooled evolution",1200,12590,true},
         {"Yamaha","XSR900","in-lined 3-cylinder engine",900,9999,true}
        };

int i;
for(i=0; i<4; i++)
{
 printf("\n Motocyrcle company: %s",Motorcycles[i].company);
 printf("\n Motorcycle model: %s",Motorcycles[i].model_name);
 printf("\n Motorcycle engine type: %s",Motorcycles[i].engine_type);
 printf("\n Motorcycle engien volume: %d",Motorcycles[i].engine_volume);
 printf("\n Motorcycle price: %d",Motorcycles[i].price);
 printf("\n Motorcycle available: %b",Motorcycles[i].available);
}

char user_input;
printf("Would you like to save it to file?\n");
scanf("%c",&user_input);

FILE *file_open;

if(user_input == 'y')
{
 file_open = fopen("motorcycles.txt","w");
 fwrite(&Motorcycles[4],sizeof(struct Motorcycle),1,file_open); fclose(file_open);
 printf("bikes copied");
 fclose(file_open);
}
 else
 {
  printf("Goodbye!");
  fclose(file_open);
 }



return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should check whether `fopen("motorcycles.txt","w")` failed in the first place.

Comment: it is opening ,since the text file was empty.

Comment: `fwrite` is just writing the raw bytes of your structure.  If you want them to be human-readable, then you need to convert them to strings.  The easiest way to do so is to use `fprintf`.

Comment: thanks , that is exactly what i was thinking about

Comment: `Motorcycles[4]` doesn't exist. You can't write it out. remember, indices in C go from `0..n-1`

Comment: `fopen("motorcycles.txt","w");` will _destroy_ the existing contents of the file.

Comment: Also you attempt to print out the content of 6 structures while you only have 4 allocated. There is some undefined behavior going on here.

Comment: You want `fwrite(Motorcycles,sizeof(struct Motorcycle),4,file_open);`

Comment: @RobertS supports Monica Cellio yep ,i did it because i cutted it out a bit ,so it would be shorter to read. Thx

Comment: @PaulOgilvie thank you ,i messed up with the fwrite parameters. Now it is working just fine!

Answer (score 1):

indeed i messed up with givineg wrong parameters to fopen() ,so as told here instead of:

```
fwrite(&Motorcycles[4],sizeof(struct Motorcycle),1,file_open);
```

must be:

```
fwrite(Motorcycles,sizeof(struct Motorcycle),4,file_open);
```

Also will try the string converting solution to check the difference.

Thanks everyone.